# Display value in html <input> tag from sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, variables, parameter-passing

I am passing a value from one HTML page to another page using the Javascript sessionStorage method. I'm able to get the value in the second page but can't display it inside a textbox.
The following is the code that I have done

**Page 1:**

```
<script>
function passvalue()
{
    var name = document.getElementById("myname").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("textvalue",name);
    return false;
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="test2">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="myname">Name :</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myname" placeholder="Enter Name...">
    </div>
  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="passvalue();">
</form>
```

**Page 2:**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=sessionStorage.getItem("textvalue");
</script>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <label for="display">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="result" name="display" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the Second page, the value of the textbox always shows as 'result' and not the name passed in the first page.

Answer (score 2):

In the second page you forgot to set `id` to the input element.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <label for="display">Name:</label>
        <input id="result" type="text" value="result" name="display" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

`EDIT:`

try to remove `value="result"`
`<input id="result" type="text"  name="display" disabled>`
and call after on load event from the document

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById('result').value = sessionStorage.getItem('textValue');
});
```

Comment: Thank you,i tried doing this but it still shows the value as result.

Comment: @SaishMahale verify the Edit section